# ATTR passando _blank

Tags: jquery

O código abaixo redireciona para outra pagina, porém gostaria que fosse em outra aba do navegador, por isso usei o _blank. más não vai para outra aba.

Alguém poderia me falar onde estou errando? Obrigado pessoal.

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
$('#veranexo').click(function(){       
   var ass_id = $("#ass_id").val();
   $(location).attr('href','<?php echo base_url() ?>/dashboard/usuarios/excluir/'+ass_id);
   $(location).attr("target","_blank");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em vez de usar `location`, use `window.open`:

```
$('#veranexo').click(function(){
   var ass_id = $("#ass_id").val();
   window.open(
     '<?php echo base_url() ?>/dashboard/usuarios/excluir/'+ass_id,
     '_blank'
   );
});
```

Irá abrir a URL numa nova aba ao clicar no elemento `#veranexo`. Alterar o `location.href` apenas altera a página da aba atual, não tem como aplicar um `target` nessa propriedade.

Comment: Imoral. muito obrigado cara. funcionou!